# Number of decimal places to be considered in division

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

This must be a basic question. But i need some help.

What is the number of decimal places that needs to be considered normally in division operations in order to represent the dividend value as a multiple of divisor and quotient by rounding off.

Example:
Say i want to divide 3475934 and 3475935 by 65536.

For first number: 
 3475934 / 65536 = 53.03854 So when I multiply the quotient with the divisor i get 3475933.75 which i am rounding of to 3475934

For second number:
3475935 / 65536 = 53.03855. And the result will be approximately 3475934.41. In this case if I round of i will be getting  the same value again 3475934.

But, If I consider one more decimal place I can round of to the original value

Is it possible to somehow calculate the number of decimal places to be considered ?

Comment: You might want to read this page on [*Precision*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_(arithmetic)) follwoed by [*Round Off Error*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error)

Comment: @Amzoti: Hi thanks for the links. So there aren't any ways to determine the decimal places. The only thing i can do is that keep more decimal places so that the round off error will be minimum.

Comment: If you use an infinite precision library, it couldn't hurt.