# How to estimate the number of decimal places required for a division?

Tags: rational-numbers

Given two decimal numbers, **is it possible to estimate the number of decimal places required to fit the result of their division?** Provided that the division yields a finite number of decimals, of course.

For example:

- `1234.5678` / `2` = `617.2839`, 4 decimal places required
- `1234.5678` / `4` = `308.64195`, 5 decimal places  required
- `1234.5678` / `8` = `154.320975`, 6 decimal places  required
- `1234.5678` / `6.4` = `192.90121875`, 8 decimal places  required

By *estimate*, I don't necessarily need the *exact* number of decimals in the result, but a number of decimals *at least equal to* the required amount, so that it is guaranteed that the result fits.

---

## What I've tried

I was able to roughly solve my problem using rational numbers & prime factorization, but this is very compute expensive. Here are the steps:

- Take the original division: `1234.5678 / 6.4`
- Convert it to a rational number: `12345678 / 64000`
- Simplify this fraction using the GCD of the two numbers: `6172839 / 32000`
- Take the denominator: `32000`
- Compute the factors of `2` and `5` by dividing successively by these two numbers:
  `32000`= 2<sup>8</sup> * 5<sup>3</sup>
- *(if it is found at this step that the number has other factors than `2` and `5`, then stop here: the division yields an infinite number of digits)*
- Take the maximum of the two exponents: `max(8,3) = 8`
- **⇒ 8 decimal places is enough to fit the result of the division.**

### How I came to the conclusion above

Out of all the prime numbers, only dividing by `2` and `5` yields a finite number of digits.

Each division by 10 extends the scale of the decimal number by 1 digit.
Each combination of `2` and `5` yields a `10`, so an extra digit.

In 2<sup>x</sup> * 5<sup>y</sup>, there are `min(x,y)` times 10.

Now each division by `2` or `5` can *potentially* (although not always) require an extra digit. So I will carefully add an extra digit for each remaining `2` or `5` factor:

Maximum required digits = `min(x,y) + (x - min(x,y)) + (y - min(x,y))`

Which simplifies to: `x + y - min(x,y)`

Which further simplifies to `max(x,y)`.

---

I feel like my approach, although it works, is overly complex. The direct consequence on my software is the slowness of the algorithm.

**Is there a more straightforward approach to estimating the number of decimal places required for the result of the division to fit?**

Note that I've read this question: [Number of decimal places to be considered in division](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/429127/19636) but it didn't help.

Comment: I don't *think* there is a simpler way. Good work though.

Comment: I don't see why you think your algorithm is overly complex. In what context is it too slow?

Comment: @RobArthan It involves calculating the GCD, which is a recursive algorithm requiring to calculate several times the remainder of a division; then to decompose in factors 2 and 5, which requires again a number of divisions that is dependent on the size of the number. That's a lot of divisions to calculate the scale of the result of a single division! Especially for an arbitrary-size numbers library.

Comment: So this is about memory management in an arbitrary size arithmetic library you are designing? Why can't you allocate memory as you do the division? In any case, you need to quantify the time and space problems you are concerned about. Just saying "lots of divisions" doesn't help anybody to understand your problem. GCD is easily calculated using a loop if you find the performance of recursion worrying, but if that is the case then your problem is a computer science problem not a mathematical one. Why not use GMP? Or see how GMP does it?

Comment: @RobArthan My library does use GMP when available. This is not about memory management, but rather about clock cycles required to compute the result. Every division is compute-heavy, so if there's a cleverer way to achieve the same result with less divisions, I'll take it! If none, then my approach will be good enough, I guess.

Comment: But your question is about the number of decimal places required for the result of the division. Why do you need to know that in advance to achieve a fast algorithm?

Comment: Ah, you misunderstood the question, I guess. I don't need the scale to make the division faster. I need the scale so that I can allocate the number of digits of the decimal result before doing the division. Like to divide `1234.5678 / 6.4`, which is `12345678 / 64000`, I will actually divide `1234567800000000 / 64000` (adding `8` zeros to the numerator), so I can be sure that this division will have no remainder. The result, `19290121875`, will be associated with the scale `8` to form the decimal `192.90121875`. I need to compute this scale before the division, as fast as possible.

Comment: I apologise for my misunderstanding of your question. My reading of your question led me to think that you wanted to know how many digits to allocate to the result of a division problem. However, your last comment tells me that you what you actually wanted to know was how many digits to allocate to the result of a division problem. I'm afraid this distinction is too subtle for me.

Comment: I'm not sure how I should understand your comment?

Comment: I'm not sure how to make it clearer. If you ask me to divide `1234.5678` by `6.4` rounded to 2 decimals, then easy, I'll divide internally `1234567800 / 64000` and retain the quotient. If you don't hint me on the scale of the result, then I need to do some extra computation to pre-calculate *how many zeros I have to add to the numerator* before doing the division. And I'm trying to make this computation faster, assuming that there might be a cleverer method than mine. Hence this question.

Comment: Note: My final implementation is [here](https://github.com/brick/math/blob/510f506185d4c988f97180426ec80fb3dbf51e04/src/BigDecimal.php#L261-L290).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calculating the maximum precision needed to reserve a place for the result?

Look how Java's BigDecimal does that:

https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/da0da73ab82ed714dc5be94acd2f0d00fbdfe2e9/src/share/classes/java/math/BigDecimal.java#L1674

Then the non-terminating numbers will cause an overflow of this area, so just check for this corner case during calculation and if that will happen, you can be sure it cannot be precisely expressed as decimal number.