# What is maximum number of fractional decimal digits required for exact division?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, rational-numbers

I am interested in understanding the maximum number of fractional decimal digits required for exact division.

The Java BigDecimal implementation states (and implements):

> If the quotient this/divisor has a terminating decimal
> expansion, the expansion can have no more than
> (a.precision() + ceil(10*b.precision)/3)
>  digits.

There is a typo/parenthesis error in the Java BigDecimal source comment.
It should read

> (a.precision() + ceil(10*b.precision/3))

In this context *precision* is used as in computer representations of floating point numbers (e.g. IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic 754-2008). It can be thought of as the number of digits in the significand/coefficient/mantissa *s* when a terminating decimal is written in base 10 scientific notation s * 10<sup>e</sup> where *s* has been normalized to remove all leading and trailing zeros.

Here is a snippet of the code in question:

```
            /*
             * If the quotient this/divisor has a terminating decimal
             * expansion, the expansion can have no more than
             * (a.precision() + ceil(10*b.precision)/3) digits.
             * Therefore, create a MathContext object with this
             * precision and do a divide with the UNNECESSARY rounding
             * mode.
             */
            MathContext mc = new MathContext( (int)Math.min(this.precision() +
                                                            (long)Math.ceil(10.0*divisor.precision()/3.0),
                                                            Integer.MAX_VALUE),
                                              RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY);
            BigDecimal quotient;
            try {
                quotient = this.divide(divisor, mc);
            } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
                throw new ArithmeticException("Non-terminating decimal expansion; " +
                                              "no exact representable decimal result.");
            }
```

This links to the BigDecimal source code:
https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/da0da73ab82ed714dc5be94acd2f0d00fbdfe2e9/src/share/classes/java/math/BigDecimal.java#L1674

I found a reference to Java BigDecimal in the answer provided by @siefca to 
[How to estimate the number of decimal places required for a division?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339411/how-to-estimate-the-number-of-decimal-places-required-for-a-division)
but, there is no explanation as to how it is derived.

Q: How is this formula for the maximum number of digits in an exact decimal division derived?

Comment: Obviously "exact" decimal division in $1/3$ is not attained in any finite number of places.  Perhaps you are asking how many places are needed to give us the repeating part of a fraction's decimal expansion?

Comment: @hardmath Thank you for your prompt response. I am not looking for how many places are needed to give the repeating part of a rational number's decimal expansion. Rather, in the case where a rational number explicitly does not repeat, how many decimal digits are required. I am looking for an explanation for dividend.precision() + ceil(10*divisor.precision()) / 3;

Comment: ^Depends on the fraction, each one is different.  The maximum possible number of digits before a non-terminating rational number repeats is one fewer than the denominator (e.g. 1/7 has a sequence of 6 digits that repeats).

Comment: What exactly is "precision" in BigDecimal? Is it the number of digits including the first non-zero digit, the last non-zero digit, and all digits in between, but not counting zeros before the first non-zero or after the last non-zero? If that's not what it is, I'm not sure how to make sense of the formula.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. In the context of Java BigDecimal "precision" refers to the number of decimal digits in the significand/mantissa. Given a number written in plain (non-scientific) notation, strip all the leading zeros and trailing zeros, independent of the decimal separator. Count the number of digits from most significant through least significant ... that gives you your precision.

Comment: @hardmath Thank you for your feedback. I have added a link to the Java BigDecimal source code lines in questions.

Comment: The simple case, of dividing two *integers* $m$ and $n$, where $m$ is an exact multiple of $n$, is worth considering first.   An obvious upper bound on the (exact) result's decimal places is $\lceil \log_{10} m \rceil - \lfloor \log_{10} n \rfloor$. I'm not familiar with the BigDecimal method `.precision` that you reference, so we should try and give Readers a mathematical definition for it.

Comment: @hardmath, I'm not capable of coming up with a mathematical definition for *precision*, but I made an attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the formulas a little more concise, let $n$ be the precision of the numerator, $d$ the precision of the denominator.
The formula in the BigDecimal implementation that bounds the precision of the quotient can then be written
$$ n + \left\lceil \frac{10d}{3} \right\rceil.$$

Note that the denominator can be multiplied by a power of $10$ to produce an integer.
That integer can have only factors of some power of $2$ and some power of $5$, since otherwise we get a non-terminating decimal fraction, which is an error.
Moreover, if we can pair up any factor of $2$ with any factor of $5$, they form a factor of $10,$ which does not contribute to the precision of the number.
So the denominator is either $2^x \times 10^y$ or $5^x \times 10^y$ or simply $10^y$ for some positive integer $x$ and some integer $y$.
(By allowing $y$ to be negative, we also account for any decimal fraction in the original denominator.)

Denominators of the form $10^y$ lead to quotients with $n$ digits of precision, so that case is dealt with easily.

Now note that each of the $x$ factors of $2$ in $2^x \times 10^y$
or $5$ in $5^x \times 10^y$ adds exactly one digit of precision (and no more) on the right-hand end of the numerator during division:

\begin{align}
\frac{9999}{2} &= 4999.5 & \frac{9999}{5} &= 1999.8 \\
\frac{9999}{2^2} &= 2499.75 & \frac{9999}{5^2} &= \phantom{0}399.96 \\
\frac{9999}{2^3} &= 1249.875 & \frac{9999}{5^3} &= \phantom{00}79.992 
\end{align}

So an upper bound on the number of digits of the quotient is simply
$n + x.$

But the formula assumes we know $d,$ not $x.$
What is the upper bound of $x$ in terms of a known value of $d$?
It's simply the exponent of the largest power of either $2$ or $5$ that you can write with $d$ digits of precision. But the exponent of that power of $2$ will always be greater than the exponent of that power of $5$. So the question is really just what power of $2$ can be written with $d$ digits of precision.

In general, for $x > 0,$ to write $2^x$ takes
$d = \lceil x\log_{10}(2) \rceil = x\log_{10}(2) + f$ digits, where $0\leq f < 1.$
Solving for $x,$

$$
x = \frac{d - f}{\log_{10}(2)} \leq \frac{d}{\log_{10}(2)} < \frac{d}{0.3}
 = \frac{10d}{3} \leq \left\lceil\frac{10d}{3} \right\rceil
$$
since $\log_{10}(2) > 0.3.$ And so
$n + x \leq n + \left\lceil {10d/3} \right\rceil,$
and since $n + x$ is an upper bound on the precision of the quotient,
so is $n + \left\lceil {10d/3} \right\rceil.$
That proves the correctness of the formula.

---

But the formula is not a particularly tight upper bound on the precision of the quotient. There is the substitution of $0.3$ for $\log_{10}$, which hardly ever will make a difference except for very large denominators (and not much difference then).
There is also the fact that since $x \leq {d/\log_{10}(2)}$ and $x$ is an integer, by definition $x \leq \left\lfloor {d/\log_{10}(2)} \right\rfloor.$
And since $d/\log_{10}(2)$ is never an integer, that means the formula always gives an answer at least $1$ greater than required.
Since $\log_{10}(2) > 0.301,$ a slightly tighter bound would be

$$ n + \left\lfloor \frac{d}{0.301} \right\rfloor.$$

But even that is not what makes the BigDecimal formula such a loose bound.
A larger effect is due to the fact that when you repeatedly divide a number by $2,$
every third or fourth division removes one digit of precision from the left side of the number. It turns out that instead of adding $x$ digits of precision to the numerator by dividing it by $2^x,$ we add something more like $0.7 x$ digits of precision.

Another way to think about this is that dividing by $2^x$ is the same as multiplying by $5^x$ and then dividing by $10^x.$ Dividing by $10^x$ doesn't change the precision, but the multiplication by $5^x$ potentially adds as many digits of precision as the precision of $5^x,$ which is $\lceil x\log_{10}(5) \rceil.$
Since $x \leq \left\lfloor {d/\log_{10}(2)} \right\rfloor,$
this means the precision of the quotient can be at most

$$
n + \left\lceil\left\lfloor\frac{d}{\log_{10}(2)}\right\rfloor \log_{10}(5)\right\rceil
\leq  n + \left\lceil\frac{\log_{10}(5)}{\log_{10}(2)}d \right\rceil
\leq  n + \left\lceil 2.322 d \right\rceil.
$$

So an alternative formulation is that there are at most
$n + \left\lceil 2.322 d \right\rceil$ digits in the quotient.
This grows slower than the formula that was used.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response. It will take me a while to digest it, but this looks like exactly the derivation I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the formula used in Java BigDecimal to determine maximum number of significand digits for non-repeating exact decimal division David K wrote:

> ... the formula always gives an answer at least 1
> greater than required.

For a tighter upper bound David K showed:

> ... there are at most +⌈2.322⌉
> digits in the quotient. This grows slower than the formula that was used.

I wrote some Java code to demonstrate this. In the following table n and d represent numerator and denominator precision. The 10/3 column is the BigDecimal implementation. The 0.301 column is David K's slight improvement. The 2.322 column is David K's much tighter bound. The 9/pow2 column shows actual quotient significand precision with a numerator of 9 (max value with n == 1) and a denominator of the max power of 2 that fits in d digits.

```
    n     d =>  10/3 0.301 2.322 9/pow2 
 ----  ---- => ----- ----- ----- ------ 
    1     1 =>     5     4     4      4 
    1     2 =>     8     7     6      6 
    1     3 =>    11    10     8      8 
    1     4 =>    15    14    11     11 
    1     5 =>    18    17    13     13 
    1     6 =>    21    20    15     15 
    1     7 =>    25    24    18     18 
    1     8 =>    28    27    20     20 
    1     9 =>    31    30    22     22 
    1    10 =>    35    34    25     25 
    1    20 =>    68    67    48     48 
    1    30 =>   101   100    71     71 
    1    40 =>   135   133    94     94 
    1    50 =>   168   167   118    117 not exact
    1    60 =>   201   200   141    141 
    1    70 =>   235   233   164    164 
    1    80 =>   268   266   187    187 
    1    90 =>   301   300   210    210 
    1   100 =>   335   333   234    234 
    1   200 =>   668   665   466    466 
    1   300 =>  1001   997   698    698 
    1   400 =>  1335  1329   930    930 
    1   500 =>  1668  1662  1162   1162 
    1   600 =>  2001  1994  1395   1395 
    1   700 =>  2335  2326  1627   1627 
    1   800 =>  2668  2658  1859   1859 
    1   900 =>  3001  2991  2091   2091 
    1  1000 =>  3335  3323  2323   2323 
total not exact:186
```

One can see that 2.322 column is significantly tighter, usually exact and never off by more than one for d up thru 1000. The formula predicts one digit more than is actually required in 186 cases in the range [1, 1000].

In the case of n == 1 d == 50 the formula predicts 118 digits of significand precision when, in fact, 9/(2**50) requires 117 decimal significand digits.

Here is the Java source code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

class QuotientPrecisionBound {
    
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        testQuotientPrecisionBound();
    }

    static int calcQuotBound3(int n, int d) {
        int q = n + (int)Math.ceil((10 * d)/ 3.0);
        return q;
    }
    
    static int calcQuotBound301(int n, int d) {
        int q = n + (int)(d / 0.301);
        return q;
    }
    
    static int calcQuotBound2322(int n, int d) {
        int q = n + (int) Math.ceil(2.322 * d);
        return q;
    }
    
    static int nineDivPow2Precision(int d) {
        int exponent = (int)(d / Math.log10(2.0));
        BigDecimal pow2 = BigDecimal.valueOf(2).pow(exponent);
        BigDecimal quotient = BigDecimal.valueOf(9).divide(pow2);
        /*
        if (d == 50) {
            System.out.printf("d == %s\n2**50 == %s\n9/2**50 == %s\n",
                    d, pow2, quotient);
        }
        */
        int precision = quotient.precision();
        return precision;
    }
    
    final static int D_MAX = 1000;
    
    final static String FORMAT = "%5s %5s => %5s %5s %5s %6s %s\n";
    
    static void testQuotientPrecisionBound() {
        System.out.printf(FORMAT, "n", "d", "10/3", "0.301", "2.322", "9/pow2", "");
        System.out.printf(FORMAT, "----", "----", "-----", "-----", "-----", "------", "");
        int notExactCount = 0;
        int n = 1;
        for (int d = 1; d <= D_MAX; ++d) {
            int quotBound10_3 = calcQuotBound3(n, d);
            int quotBound301 = calcQuotBound301(n, d);
            int quotBound2322 = calcQuotBound2322(n, d);
            int nineDivPow2 = nineDivPow2Precision(d);

            boolean exactMatch = quotBound2322 == nineDivPow2;
            if (! exactMatch)
                ++notExactCount;

            if (d < 10 ||
                    d < 100 && d % 10 == 0 ||
                    d % 100 == 0) {
                System.out.printf(FORMAT, n, d, 
                        quotBound10_3, quotBound301, quotBound2322, nineDivPow2,
                        exactMatch ? "" : "not exact");
            }
            if (quotBound2322 < nineDivPow2)
                throw new RuntimeException("didn't fit!");
            if (quotBound2322 - nineDivPow2 > 1)
                throw new RuntimeException("difference of more than one");

        }
        System.out.printf("total not exact:%s\n", notExactCount);
    }
    
}
```